# Java NoClassDefFound Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run a basic Hibernate program.
When I run it, I am getting the below error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger

I tried google'ing for it and did include the following jar files in my classpath :-

- jboss-common-3.2.3.jar
- jboss-common-client-3.2.3.jar

Am I missing some more jar file ?

Thanks

---

**EDIT :**

I did include the following jar file inside classpath :-

- jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR1.jar

But, Facing the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Lj‌​ava/lang/Object
```

Comment: did you include the necessary classes in your code?

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError` means that you most likely are trying to run this with a different version of the JAR file than what you compiled it with. Make sure you use the same version of the JAR when compiling and when running your program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes `jboss-logging.jar` `org/jboss/logging/BasicLogger` is inside `jboss-logging.jar`

You can find list of dependent jar for this jar in used by section in [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.1.Final).

This version should contain [the method](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.1.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.1.GA.jar).

Comment: Thanks, that did resolved that error. But it's not giving me another error .. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: You can find more info on [How to create a simple EJB3 project in Eclipse (JBoss 7.1)](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-a-simple-ejb3-project-in-eclipse-jboss-7-1/). You will also find list of dependent jars over there.

Comment: to **resolve all those dependencies in a standalone (non-container-managed) environment** it may help to just download a hibernate release from here: http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/ and add all the jars from under **`hibernate-release-*-Final/lib/required/*.jar`** (e.g. 9 jars for 4.3.7)

Comment: (of course depending on what you are doing, further libs may be required or "/required/*.jar" ones may not be required for your specific scenario)

Answer (score 4):

You need jboss-logging.jar

You can get it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjbossloggingjar.htm)

Comment: Getting this error now ..java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Lj‌​ava/lang/Object;

Answer (score 1):

If those files already exist, try adding them to your `Java Build Path`. 
You can use this as reference: [Java Build Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729587/java-build-path-add-external-jars-and-add-variable)

Answer (score 1):

To solve

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Lj‌​ava/lang/Object
```

use the JAR file (jboss-client-7.1.0.Final.jar) this will help you to solve solve your error

Comment: I tried google'ing that jar but couldn't find the link. Can you pls provide me with d/w link ?