# Unable to create session factory in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, session, log4j

I am learning hibernate 4 but got stuck in creation of **Session Factory**
and please review my code and help me to find out the cause of problem as i am using hibernate-core 5.0.6, MySQL connector 5.0.8, log4j 1.2.17,jta jar,dom4j,and jboss-logging jar and this is my code for session factory

```
class HibernateUtill 
{

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        static {
            try {
                Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Mylogger");
                logger.info("Trying to create a test connection with database");
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
                configuration.configure();
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration
                        .getProperties());
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                System.out.println("SessionFactory creation failed with error" + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }

        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;

        }

        public static void shutDown() {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
}
```

and the error I'm getting is :

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
SessionFactory creation failed with errororg.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.commonClasses.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    at com.java.save.SavingObject.savingObject(SavingObject.java:13)
    at com.java.save.SavingObject.main(SavingObject.java:31)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:259)
    at com.commonClasses.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 2 more
```

or in simple terms **errororg.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource**

The things I know is the error is due to log4j and I placed log4j.properties in src folder and the code for the property file is

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootlogger=INFO,stdout

#Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

#log JDBC bind parameter runtime arguments
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

please help me to solve this error and cause of this error too.
any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: seems that a jar is missing or different versions of it (jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR1.jar) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615566/java-noclassdeffound-error

Comment: yeah now i got this i was missing jboss-logging,dom4j ,and jta jar but now i am stuck with other message **Could not locate cfg.xml resource**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a **hibernate.cfg.xml** like:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> <hibernate-configuration>   <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
     <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>

      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->   </session-factory> </hibernate-configuration>
```

Add next code to your **servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

And create **.properties** file with next code

```
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB
database.user=user
database.password=password
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

After that you could create hibernate session with next code

```
Session session = null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String query = "select users.username, users.password, users.name, users.enabled, users.surname, users.email, users.gender, users.age, users.weight, users.height, users.sport, users.place, users.photo from users where users.username LIKE '%s'";
    List<Users> userInfoList = session.createSQLQuery(String.format(query, username)).addEntity(Users.class).list();
    session.close();
    session = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the hibernate config file in your class path. That can be named ad `cfg.xml` . Below is example for the config file. configure these elements for your DB and place this in class path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:3306/hibernatetrial?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>
        <mapping resource="hibernatemapping/mapping.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: now i got it by changing the approach like
**sessionFactory= new  Configuration().configure("configration.cfg.xml").addResource("Employee.hbm.xml").buildSessionFactory();**

Comment: but now if I'm using same approach for two **xxx.hbm.xml** its not working
can you help me with that and one thing i'm working with java code not servlet or jsp/spring and no annotations please

Comment: Check whether your config file in the class path. Whether container able to load this file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Comment: In your code you did not pass .cfg.xml file,which contains DB connection details.